# Laravel 4 facade class not calling functions on facade root class

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, facade

I've set up a package in laravel 4 via the artisan workbench command. I created a facade class and followed [this tutorial](http://fideloper.com/create-facade-laravel-4) to come up with the following service provider, facade and root classes:

src/Spoolphiz/Infusionsoft/InfusionsoftServiceProvider.php:

```
namespace Spoolphiz\Infusionsoft;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class InfusionsoftServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = false;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application events.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->package('spoolphiz/infusionsoft');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {   
        // Register 'infusionsoft' instance container to our Infusionsoft object
        $this->app['infusionsoft'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new Spoolphiz\Infusionsoft\Infusionsoft;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return array();
    }

}
```

src/Spoolphiz/Infusionsoft/Facades/Facade.php:

```
namespace Spoolphiz\Infusionsoft\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Infusionsoft extends Facade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'infusionsoft'; }

}
```

Finally I've set up the underlying class thats to be connected to the facade at src/Spoolphiz/Infusionsoft/Infusionsoft.php:

```
namespace Spoolphiz\Infusionsoft;

//use Spoolphiz\Infusionsoft\iSDK;
/*
This is hackish and a un-laravel way to handle the requirement of \iSDK but unfortunately the xmlrpc3.0 lib doesn't want to correctly encode values when run with a namespace. Will try to resolve this later.
*/
require_once(__DIR__.'/isdk.php');

class Infusionsoft extends \iSDK {

    protected $_app;

    /**
    * Init the sdk
    * 
    */
    public function __construct( $connectionName )
    {           
        $this->_app = parent::cfgCon($connectionName);
    }

    public function test()
    {
        dd('works');
    }
}
```

I set up the service provider and the facade alias of Infusionsoft in app/config/config.php.
When I try running methods belonging to the extended iSDK class against an instance of Spoolphiz\Infusionsoft\Facade\Infusionsoft I get undefined method errors, such as the following:

Call to undefined method Spoolphiz\Infusionsoft\Facades\Infusionsoft::loadCon()

Why is this? The whole point of facades is to be able to call methods against its root class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I was being stupid. I was developing this package in the laravel workbench. Once it was done I submitted it to packagist and set up a requirement for it in the same laravel app. Having the package installed in vendors directory and in the workbench caused some sort of conflict.

Lesson learned: make sure you dont have the same package in your workbench and in your application's vendors directory.